# Почему в js не работает height:auto?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Как сделать чтобы высота картинки в блоке была `auto`? Т.е ширина картинки всегда 100%, а высота блока подстраивалась по пропорциональной высоте картинки.

```js
$(".entry-page .entry-inner").each(function() {
 $(this).css({
  "background-image": "url(" + $(this).find("img").attr("src") + ")",
  "width": "100%",
    "height": "200px" // Здесь auto не работает
 }), $(this).find("img").remove(), $(this).append('<div class="glitch_hover_img"></div><div class="glitch_hover_img"></div><div class="glitch_hover_img"></div><div class="glitch_hover_img"></div><div class="glitch_hover_img"></div>')
});
```

```css
.box {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 5px solid green;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.responsive-img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.entry-page {
 opacity: 1!important;
}    
.entry-page .entry-inner {
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 background-size: cover;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 max-width: 100%;
}    
.glitch_hover_img {
 position: absolute;
 top: calc(-1 * 2px);
 left: calc(-1 * 20px);
 width: calc(100% + 20px * 2);
 height: calc(100% + 2px * 2);
 background-image: inherit;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: inherit;
 background-color: transparent;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 background-blend-mode: transparent;
 background-size: cover;
 opacity: 0;
}

.release-hover-effect-glitch .entry-release .img-bg {
 opacity: 1!important;
 background-size: cover;
}

.entry-page:hover .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(n+2),.release-hover-effect-glitch .entry-release:hover .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(n+2),.wvc-interactive-link-item a:hover .wvc-ils-item-title .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(n+2) {
 opacity: 1;
}

.entry-page:hover .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(2),.release-hover-effect-glitch .entry-release:hover .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(2),.wvc-interactive-link-item a:hover .wvc-ils-item-title .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(20px,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(20px,0,0);
 -webkit-animation: glitch-anim-1-horizontal 3s infinite linear alternate;
 animation: glitch-anim-1-horizontal 3s infinite linear alternate;
}

.entry-page:hover .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(3),.release-hover-effect-glitch .entry-release:hover .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(3),.wvc-interactive-link-item a:hover .wvc-ils-item-title .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(calc(-1 * 20px),0,0);
 transform: translate3d(calc(-1 * 20px),0,0);
 -webkit-animation: glitch-anim-2-horizontal 3s infinite linear alternate;
 animation: glitch-anim-2-horizontal 3s infinite linear alternate;
}

.entry-page:hover .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(4),.release-hover-effect-glitch .entry-release:hover .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(4),.wvc-interactive-link-item a:hover .wvc-ils-item-title .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(4) {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,calc(-1 * 2px),0) scale3d(-1,-1,1);
 transform: translate3d(0,calc(-1 * 2px),0) scale3d(-1,-1,1);
 -webkit-animation: glitch-anim-3-horizontal 3s infinite linear alternate;
 animation: glitch-anim-3-horizontal 3s infinite linear alternate;
}

.entry-page:hover .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(5),.release-hover-effect-glitch .entry-release:hover .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(5),.wvc-interactive-link-item a:hover .wvc-ils-item-title .glitch_hover_img:nth-child(5) {
 -webkit-animation: glitch-anim-1-flash .7s steps(1,end) infinite;
 animation: glitch-anim-1-flash .7s steps(1,end) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glitch-anim-1-flash {
 0% {
  opacity: .2;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(20px,2px,0);
  transform: translate3d(20px,2px,0);
 }

 100%,33% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 }
}

@keyframes glitch-anim-1-flash {
 0% {
  opacity: .2;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(20px,2px,0);
  transform: translate3d(20px,2px,0);
 }

 100%,33% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes glitch-anim-1-horizontal {
 0% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 2%,100% 2%,100% 5%,0 5%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 2%,100% 2%,100% 5%,0 5%);
 }

 10% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 15%,100% 15%,100% 15%,0 15%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 15%,100% 15%,100% 15%,0 15%);
 }

 20% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 10%,100% 10%,100% 20%,0 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 10%,100% 10%,100% 20%,0 20%);
 }

 30% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 1%,100% 1%,100% 2%,0 2%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 1%,100% 1%,100% 2%,0 2%);
 }

 40% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 33%,100% 33%,100% 33%,0 33%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 33%,100% 33%,100% 33%,0 33%);
 }

 50% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 44%,100% 44%,100% 44%,0 44%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 44%,100% 44%,100% 44%,0 44%);
 }

 60% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 50%,100% 50%,100% 20%,0 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 50%,100% 50%,100% 20%,0 20%);
 }

 70% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 70%,0 70%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 70%,0 70%);
 }

 80% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 80%,100% 80%,100% 80%,0 80%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 80%,100% 80%,100% 80%,0 80%);
 }

 90% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 50%,100% 50%,100% 55%,0 55%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 50%,100% 50%,100% 55%,0 55%);
 }

 100% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 80%,0 80%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 80%,0 80%);
 }
}

@keyframes glitch-anim-1-horizontal {
 0% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 2%,100% 2%,100% 5%,0 5%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 2%,100% 2%,100% 5%,0 5%);
 }

 10% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 15%,100% 15%,100% 15%,0 15%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 15%,100% 15%,100% 15%,0 15%);
 }

 20% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 10%,100% 10%,100% 20%,0 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 10%,100% 10%,100% 20%,0 20%);
 }

 30% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 1%,100% 1%,100% 2%,0 2%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 1%,100% 1%,100% 2%,0 2%);
 }

 40% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 33%,100% 33%,100% 33%,0 33%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 33%,100% 33%,100% 33%,0 33%);
 }

 50% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 44%,100% 44%,100% 44%,0 44%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 44%,100% 44%,100% 44%,0 44%);
 }

 60% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 50%,100% 50%,100% 20%,0 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 50%,100% 50%,100% 20%,0 20%);
 }

 70% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 70%,0 70%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 70%,0 70%);
 }

 80% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 80%,100% 80%,100% 80%,0 80%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 80%,100% 80%,100% 80%,0 80%);
 }

 90% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 50%,100% 50%,100% 55%,0 55%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 50%,100% 50%,100% 55%,0 55%);
 }

 100% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 80%,0 80%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 80%,0 80%);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes glitch-anim-2-horizontal {
 0% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 25%,100% 25%,100% 30%,0 30%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 25%,100% 25%,100% 30%,0 30%);
 }

 15% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 3%,100% 3%,100% 3%,0 3%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 3%,100% 3%,100% 3%,0 3%);
 }

 22% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 5%,100% 5%,100% 20%,0 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 5%,100% 5%,100% 20%,0 20%);
 }

 31% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 20%,100% 20%,100% 20%,0 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%,100% 20%,100% 20%,0 20%);
 }

 45% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 40%,100% 40%,100% 40%,0 40%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 40%,100% 40%,100% 40%,0 40%);
 }

 51% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 52%,100% 52%,100% 59%,0 59%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 52%,100% 52%,100% 59%,0 59%);
 }

 63% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 60%,100% 60%,100% 60%,0 60%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 60%,100% 60%,100% 60%,0 60%);
 }

 76% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 75%,100% 75%,100% 75%,0 75%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 75%,100% 75%,100% 75%,0 75%);
 }

 81% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 65%,100% 65%,100% 40%,0 40%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 65%,100% 65%,100% 40%,0 40%);
 }

 94% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 45%,100% 45%,100% 50%,0 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 45%,100% 45%,100% 50%,0 50%);
 }

 100% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 14%,100% 14%,100% 33%,0 33%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 14%,100% 14%,100% 33%,0 33%);
 }
}

@keyframes glitch-anim-2-horizontal {
 0% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 25%,100% 25%,100% 30%,0 30%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 25%,100% 25%,100% 30%,0 30%);
 }

 15% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 3%,100% 3%,100% 3%,0 3%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 3%,100% 3%,100% 3%,0 3%);
 }

 22% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 5%,100% 5%,100% 20%,0 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 5%,100% 5%,100% 20%,0 20%);
 }

 31% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 20%,100% 20%,100% 20%,0 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%,100% 20%,100% 20%,0 20%);
 }

 45% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 40%,100% 40%,100% 40%,0 40%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 40%,100% 40%,100% 40%,0 40%);
 }

 51% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 52%,100% 52%,100% 59%,0 59%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 52%,100% 52%,100% 59%,0 59%);
 }

 63% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 60%,100% 60%,100% 60%,0 60%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 60%,100% 60%,100% 60%,0 60%);
 }

 76% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 75%,100% 75%,100% 75%,0 75%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 75%,100% 75%,100% 75%,0 75%);
 }

 81% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 65%,100% 65%,100% 40%,0 40%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 65%,100% 65%,100% 40%,0 40%);
 }

 94% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 45%,100% 45%,100% 50%,0 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 45%,100% 45%,100% 50%,0 50%);
 }

 100% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 14%,100% 14%,100% 33%,0 33%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 14%,100% 14%,100% 33%,0 33%);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes glitch-anim-3-horizontal {
 0% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 1%,100% 1%,100% 3%,0 3%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 1%,100% 1%,100% 3%,0 3%);
 }

 5% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 10%,100% 10%,100% 9%,0 9%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 10%,100% 10%,100% 9%,0 9%);
 }

 10% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 5%,100% 5%,100% 6%,0 6%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 5%,100% 5%,100% 6%,0 6%);
 }

 25% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 20%,100% 20%,100% 20%,0 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%,100% 20%,100% 20%,0 20%);
 }

 27% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 10%,100% 10%,100% 10%,0 10%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 10%,100% 10%,100% 10%,0 10%);
 }

 30% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 30%,100% 30%,100% 25%,0 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 30%,100% 30%,100% 25%,0 25%);
 }

 33% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 15%,100% 15%,100% 16%,0 16%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 15%,100% 15%,100% 16%,0 16%);
 }

 37% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 40%,100% 40%,100% 39%,0 39%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 40%,100% 40%,100% 39%,0 39%);
 }

 40% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 20%,100% 20%,100% 21%,0 21%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%,100% 20%,100% 21%,0 21%);
 }

 45% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 60%,100% 60%,100% 55%,0 55%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 60%,100% 60%,100% 55%,0 55%);
 }

 50% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 30%,100% 30%,100% 31%,0 31%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 30%,100% 30%,100% 31%,0 31%);
 }

 53% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 69%,0 69%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 69%,0 69%);
 }

 57% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 40%,100% 40%,100% 41%,0 41%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 40%,100% 40%,100% 41%,0 41%);
 }

 60% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 80%,100% 80%,100% 75%,0 75%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 80%,100% 80%,100% 75%,0 75%);
 }

 65% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 50%,100% 50%,100% 51%,0 51%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 50%,100% 50%,100% 51%,0 51%);
 }

 70% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 90%,100% 90%,100% 90%,0 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 90%,100% 90%,100% 90%,0 90%);
 }

 73% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 60%,100% 60%,100% 60%,0 60%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 60%,100% 60%,100% 60%,0 60%);
 }

 80% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%,100% 100%,100% 99%,0 99%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%,100% 100%,100% 99%,0 99%);
 }

 100% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 71%,0 71%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 71%,0 71%);
 }
}

@keyframes glitch-anim-3-horizontal {
 0% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 1%,100% 1%,100% 3%,0 3%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 1%,100% 1%,100% 3%,0 3%);
 }

 5% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 10%,100% 10%,100% 9%,0 9%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 10%,100% 10%,100% 9%,0 9%);
 }

 10% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 5%,100% 5%,100% 6%,0 6%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 5%,100% 5%,100% 6%,0 6%);
 }

 25% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 20%,100% 20%,100% 20%,0 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%,100% 20%,100% 20%,0 20%);
 }

 27% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 10%,100% 10%,100% 10%,0 10%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 10%,100% 10%,100% 10%,0 10%);
 }

 30% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 30%,100% 30%,100% 25%,0 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 30%,100% 30%,100% 25%,0 25%);
 }

 33% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 15%,100% 15%,100% 16%,0 16%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 15%,100% 15%,100% 16%,0 16%);
 }

 37% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 40%,100% 40%,100% 39%,0 39%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 40%,100% 40%,100% 39%,0 39%);
 }

 40% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 20%,100% 20%,100% 21%,0 21%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%,100% 20%,100% 21%,0 21%);
 }

 45% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 60%,100% 60%,100% 55%,0 55%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 60%,100% 60%,100% 55%,0 55%);
 }

 50% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 30%,100% 30%,100% 31%,0 31%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 30%,100% 30%,100% 31%,0 31%);
 }

 53% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 69%,0 69%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 69%,0 69%);
 }

 57% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 40%,100% 40%,100% 41%,0 41%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 40%,100% 40%,100% 41%,0 41%);
 }

 60% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 80%,100% 80%,100% 75%,0 75%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 80%,100% 80%,100% 75%,0 75%);
 }

 65% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 50%,100% 50%,100% 51%,0 51%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 50%,100% 50%,100% 51%,0 51%);
 }

 70% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 90%,100% 90%,100% 90%,0 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 90%,100% 90%,100% 90%,0 90%);
 }

 73% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 60%,100% 60%,100% 60%,0 60%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 60%,100% 60%,100% 60%,0 60%);
 }

 80% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%,100% 100%,100% 99%,0 99%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%,100% 100%,100% 99%,0 99%);
 }

 100% {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 71%,0 71%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 70%,100% 70%,100% 71%,0 71%);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
<a href="#" class="entry-page">
    <span class="entry-inner mySingleImage">
        <img src="https://wmpics.pics/di-HTCR.png" class="responsive-img">
    </span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно попробовать `.box {background-image: url('ссылка'); background-size: cover; }` — Последнее накроет весь блок картинкой.

Comment: А как вы устанавливаете `auto`?

Comment: Не понял вопроса! `"width": "100%","height": "auto"` И получается высота равна 0

Comment: Вариантов больше нет?